# Error installing Py3ODE (Win10)

Tags: python, windows

Trying to install Py3ODE under Windows 10 (x64) I keep getting the same error:

```
PS C:\Users\...> pip install py3ode
Collecting py3ode
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/32/cd/a35273b5edc010d43bb8ec0501d02213daa6ed7f559815c2cbdd7c32091b/Py3ODE-1.2.0.dev9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    'ode-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'ode-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    WARNING: <ode/ode.h> not found. Downloading and installing it now to your home directory.
    If it's already installed you may have to adjust INC_DIRS in setup.py.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4lgahny\py3ode\setup.py", line 142, in <module>
        install_ode()
      File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y4lgahny\py3ode\setup.py", line 125, in install_ode
        subprocess.check_call(['./install_ode.sh', install_dir])
      File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I can't make sense out of the error message, don't even understand why there's a Win32 application in the first place.

Comment: %1 is a placeholder for windows files, mostly icons. Python is probaly treating an icon reference as a program reference and erroring.

Comment: @Pygasm so to solve the problem I'd need to go into the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I backtracked the problem and it's, after all, a bug in `pip` 10:

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1141

I decided to downgrade `pip` and the problem is gone.